# Yarn is not installed when Jenkins runs fastlane script

Tags: android, ios, react-native, jenkins, fastlane

I have react-native mobile projects, I have created fastlane scripts for ios and android to build and push applications. Scripts work fine if I run them manually from terminal.

But now, I want to run them from Jenkins. I work on mac system. I gave Jenkins R/W permissions to my home folder, so it be able to build applications in setted up projects. Also I've changed Jenkins's workspace, where are mobile projects are placed.

For fastlane I have installed yarn plugin. And now the trouble is that when Jenkins runs fastlane script, it seems like yarn is not installed. Here is an exception:

```
Shell command exited with exit status 127 instead of 0.
```

As I know, it tells that yarn is not installed, but it is not so, because manually launched script works fine.

So, why it happens? And what should I change? Help me please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@thekbb is right. So, what I did:

according to this [article](https://medium.com/@gustavo.guss/jenkins-starting-with-pipeline-doing-a-node-js-test-72c6057b67d4) ,  I added nodeJS plugin to Jenkins, configured it, created a pipeline in Jenkins and added this code

```
sh "npm install -g yarn"
sh "yarn install"
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is not likely running as the same user as your manual run.

When you say you installed the yarn plugin, which plugin is that? I didn't know there was one.  Do you mean [nodejs plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodejs)?

I always do this in the pipeline to get yarn installed:

```
stage('Prepare') {
    sh "npm install -g yarn"
}
```

Comment: It is fastlane-yarn plugin